# Should I save books in my inventory in Neverwinter Nights?

Tags: neverwinter-nights

I am playing Neverwinter Nights. I keep finding books and I am retaining several of them in my inventory. Should I be saving random books from bookshelves and book piles or selling them?

Things like journals that are useful for quests should obviously be kept, at least until the quest is done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The books only give you interesting stories, and sometimes backstories to in game events and characters, but there is no actual use.

I'm a bit of a pack rat though, so I collected all of them in stashes. The [fandom wiki](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Book_items) mentions those you could get rid of as having a plain, grey or blue cover, so should be easy to distinguish from quest and other items.